# Angular JS TypeError: f is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out as to why my timeout function is giving error, thereby restricting the change in model value.

***angularExample.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Tutorial">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">  
     <input type="text" ng-model="data" />
</body>
</html>
```

***app.js***

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('Tutorial', []);
app.controller("MyController",function($scope,$timeout){

    $scope.data="hi";
    $timeout(callAtTimeout,3000);

    var callAtTimeout=function(){$scope.data="hello";}
});
})();
```

***Error Snapshot:***
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define `callAtTimeout` first then use it.

```
var callAtTimeout=function(){console.log("hi")}
$timeout(callAtTimeout,3000);
```

Initializations in Javascript are not ***[hoisted](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)***.

Comment: `$timeout` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to re-arrange the order of your code, the definition for callAtTimeout function should be before you use it. Working example:

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('Tutorial', []);
app.controller("MyController",function($scope,$timeout){

    var callAtTimeout=function(){$scope.data="hello";}
    
    $scope.data="hi";
    $timeout(callAtTimeout,3000);

   
});
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Tutorial" ng-controller="MyController">  
     <input type="text" ng-model="data" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the callAtTimeout function after it its call. You need to have it above it.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3fv0Lrk/)

Sample code:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('Tutorial', []);
    app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $timeout) {

        var callAtTimeout = function () {
            $scope.data = "hello";
        }
        $scope.data = "hi";
        $timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);


 }); })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining functions such as `var callAtTimeout = function() { ... }` happens at run time, not at compile time (whereas defining functions such as `function callAtTimeout() { ... }` is at compile time).

Because of this, `callAtTimeout` is not yet defined on the line:

```
$timeout(callAtTimeout,3000);
```

Either move the declaration of `callAtTimeout` above that line, or change it to `function callAtTimeout() { ... }`

Comment: The function is defined as an anonymous function but it not assigned to the variable `callAtTimeout` until you reach the line `var callAtTimeout = function() {...}`. If you define a named function it will be available on the first line in the scope (`function myName() {...}`).

Comment: Same goes for variables: `var a = b+1; var b = 0;` Both variable `a` and `b` are defined in the top of the scope but when `a` is assigned `b` is still undefined, and `a` will therefore evaluate to `a = undefined + 1` which will result in `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

The error can also occur when two or more dependencies are misplaced. I know the answer is kinda off topic but reading this might help someone.

```
    (function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['dependency1','dependency2','dependency3'];
/* @ngInject */
function myController(dependency1, dependency3, dependency2){

    // will trigger the error    because dependency 2 && 3 are misplaced
    var v = dependency2.somefunction(arg1,arg2,...);
    // sometimes it can be difficult to see at the first look
    // especially when you have many dependencies
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had spend a lot of time trying to fix it. It was an internal error in my case.
You just have to

> break the Angular CLI (**Ctrl + c**) and
>
> run (**ng serve**) again.

It then started recognizing all my newly defined functions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `callAtTimeout` then use it.